# Calculating absolute, relative, and cumulative frequencies in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have two variables, X and Y:

```
x <- c(1.18,1.42,0.69,0.88,1.69,1.09,1.53,1.02,1.19,1.32)
y <- c(1.72,1.42,1.69,0.79,1.79,0.77,1.44,1.29,1.96,0.99)
```

I would like to create a table of the absolute, relative and cumulative frequencies of both X and Y in R

```
 plot(table(x)/length(x), type ="h", ylab = "Relative Frequency", xlim = c(0.6,1.8))
 plot(table(y)/length(y), type ="h", ylab = "Relative Frequency", xlim = c(0.6,1.8))
```

I did a sample of the relative frequency but it came out like this: [plot of the relative frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJeBQ.png). I think it is wrong. What do you think? Also, how can I use `hist(x)$counts` to obtain the absolute and cumulative frequencies?

Comment: Are x and y individual observations or are they variables? Also, please do not use links to questions since users cannot download or manipulate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wish to use `hist(x)`. Everything can be obtained using `table`:

```
# Absolute frequencies
table(x)
# x
# 0.69 0.88 1.02 1.09 1.18 1.19 1.32 1.42 1.53 1.69 
#    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 

# Relative frequencies
table(x) / length(x)
# x
# 0.69 0.88 1.02 1.09 1.18 1.19 1.32 1.42 1.53 1.69 
#  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 

# Cumulative frequencies
cumsum(table(x))
# 0.69 0.88 1.02 1.09 1.18 1.19 1.32 1.42 1.53 1.69 
#    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

and the same for `y`. As to put them together,

```
rbind(Absolute = table(x), 
      Relative = table(x) / length(x), 
      Cumulative = cumsum(table(x)))
#            0.69 0.88 1.02 1.09 1.18 1.19 1.32 1.42 1.53 1.69
# Absolute    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
# Relative    0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
# Cumulative  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0
```

The results are correct, although indeed somewhat boring. If you have more data, with repetitions, it will look better.

Comment: is it normal to get 1 for all the absolute frequencies !! and hist(x)$counts   it's an extra for me to capture the difference between x, y which i wanna ask you but I wanna send my plot but I'm new to SOF  so no clue

Comment: As I said, yes, 1 for all the absolute frequencies is correct in this case. A frequency is simply the number of times this value appears in your data. Since all your values are distinct, their frequencies are all 1. Now histogram doesn't show absolute frequencies. It selects *bins*: in the case of `x`, six bins of width 0.2, from 0.6 to 1.8. Then it computes absolute frequencies **with respect to those bins**. That may also be useful to you, but the answer to your original question is in my post.

Comment: thanks.- but what can be the difference between the two histograms of x and y 
doing     "hist(x)$counts"    "hist(y)$counts" if I should give an opinion about it ?

Comment: I guess that's not what you mean, but if you wanted to literally look at their difference, you could do `c(hist(x)$counts,0) - hist(y)$counts`. I added a zero to `x`'s histogram because it has one bin less (with no values there). This shows you differences of absolute differences of those *discretized* values (i.e., with respect to bins). Also you may plot those two histograms together and compare. You have little data, so it's hard to say something. In any case, knowing what `x` and `y` are is important. Anyway, that's not what you initial question is about.

Comment: ...If you want more help regarding *interpretation* of your results, I suggest to ask another question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: please one question .. so I did this as hist(x)$counts
    {x1 <- hist(x, breaks = c(0.25,0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 
     1.5, 1.75, 2))$counts
                                              y2 <- hist(y, breaks = c(0.25,0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 
                                              1.5, 1.75, 2))$counts
                                              absfreq <- data.frame(x1, y1, classwidth )
                                              absfreq}
as for the absolute frequency but it's not working , any ideas!!

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me your code doesn't work due to `y2` (should be `y1`?) and `classwidth`, which is undefined. Anyway, your `x1` and `y2` are indeed frequencies of `x` and `y` discretized in a certain way. It would seem that first you need to clearly understand and define what you want to find, because those are not typical frequencies of `x` and `y`, they are in my answer.