# Command for frequency table

Tags: r

Does someone know a command on R to create a frequecy table from a data.frame that display: Abs.freq, Cum.Abs.freq, Rel.freq and Cum.Rel.freq?

I've already tried:

```
prova <- data.frame(
     Variabile = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
     Freq.ass = c(1, 3, 7, 10, 17),
     Freq.ass.cum <- c(cumsum(prova$Freq.ass)),
     Freq.rel <- c(round(prop.table(prova$Freq.ass), 2)),
     Freq.rel.cum <- c(cumsum(round(prop.table(prova$Freq.ass), 2))),
     stringsAsFactors = T
     )
     
colnames(prova) <- c("Variabile", "F.Assolute", "F.Ass.Cum.", "F.Rel.", "F.Rel.Cum")`

install.packages('epiDisplay')
library(epiDisplay)
tab1(prova$Variabile~, sort.group = F, cum.percent = TRUE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252896/14992857